# Choosing a clubName

Tags: java, iteration

Please can someone advise me, how I could use a loop for this code, in the interests of code reuse.

My code is as follows

```
public class Clubs{

    public void printGreeting(int choice, String clubName[]) {


       System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");


        if (choice==1){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[0]);
        }
        if (choice==2){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[1]);
        }
        if (choice==3){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[2]);
        }
        if (choice==4){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[3]);
        }
        if (choice==5){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[4]);
        }
        if (choice==6){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[5]);
        }
        if (choice==7){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[6]);
        }
        if (choice==8){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[7]);
        }
        if (choice==9){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[8]);
        }
        if (choice==10){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[9]);
        }
        if (choice==11){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[10]);
        }
        if (choice==12){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[11]);
        }
        if (choice==13){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[12]);
        }
        if (choice==14){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[13]);
        }
        if (choice==15){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[14]);
        }
        if (choice==16){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[15]);
        }
        if (choice==17){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[16]);
        }
        if (choice==18){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[17]);
        }
        if (choice==19){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[18]);
        }
        if (choice==20){
            System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[19]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `clubName`? Full code is more welcome than partial

Comment: Couldn't you just do : `System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[choice - 1]);` ?

Answer (score 13):

A minor thing first, in Java it is recommended to use `String[] clubName` rather than `String clubName[]`. It will have the same effect, but writing `String[]` is clearer.

---

You ask for a loop, so I'll try to explain how to reach the conclusion...

Regular, normal, for loops looks like this:

```
for (int i = START; i < MAX; i++) {
    // code
}
```

In this case, as your if-statements for `choice` goes from `1` to `20`, `START` will be `1` and `MAX` will be 20. However, we need to use `<=` as we want to loop until 20 **inclusive**.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    // code
}
```

So, what about the `// code` part? Clearly it should be something like this:

```
if (choice == XXX) {
    System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[YYY]);
}
```

As the `XXX` and `YYY` parts are the only things that change in your code. Now, what exactly should we put at `XXX` and `YYY`?

XXX goes from 1 to 20, just like our `i` variable in the for-loop. So that should be `i`, but what about `YYY`? That is always one less than `i`? Should we have another for-loop to loop from 0 to 19? No! We should use the same `i` variable, we can just reduce one from it, so we get this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (choice == i) {
        System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

However, as that condition is only true once (`choice` cannot be both `4` and `7` at the same time for example), looping through all the numbers from 1 to 20 is a bit unnecessary. Instead, we can do this:

```
if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 20) {
    System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[choice - 1]);
}
```

We check if the `choice` value is between 1 and 20 (inclusive), and if it is we print out the corresponding index in `clubName`, which we get by taking `choice - 1`.

Comment: @Justin yes, fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using subtraction and array indexing to solve your problem.

```
System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[choice - 1])
```

Comment: This fails if `choice` is outside 1 - 20.

Comment: @SimonForsberg it does, an `if` to check for boundaries may be added if needed

Comment: I came in to add exactly this.